# I have a problem in my frontend under React js and openlayers Bingmap, the map does not load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, bing-maps

The satellite map does not load while the octagon does.
I think I checked everything and I think my code is correct
this is my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import logo from '../src/img/Alldem3.png';
import './AllDemande.css';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import VisibilityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import { fromLonLat, transform } from 'ol/proj';
import LineString from 'ol/geom/LineString';
import Stroke from 'ol/style/Stroke';
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import 'ol/ol.css';

function AllDemande() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedItem && selectedItem.id_terrain && selectedItem.id_terrain.coordinatesText) {
      const coordinates = selectedItem.id_terrain.coordinatesText;
      const map = new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new BingMaps({
              key: 'MySerialKey',
              imagerySet: 'Aerial',
            }),
          }),
        ],
        view: new View({
          center: fromLonLat([-6.605081, 34.200794]),
          zoom: 12,
        }),
      });
  
      const coordinatesArray = coordinates
        .split('\n')
        .map((coord) => coord.split(',').map(parseFloat));
  
      // Ajouter le premier point comme dernier point du tableau
      coordinatesArray.push(coordinatesArray[0]);
  
      const transformedCoordinates = coordinatesArray.map((coord) =>
        transform(coord, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
      );
  
      const lineString = new LineString(transformedCoordinates);
  
      const stroke = new Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        width: 2,
      });
  
      const style = new Style({
        stroke,
      });
  
      const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          features: [
            new Feature({
              geometry: lineString,
            }),
          ],
        }),
        style: style,
      });
  
      const mapLayers = map.getLayers();
      mapLayers.clear();
      mapLayers.push(vectorLayer);
    }
  }, [selectedItem]);
  
  return (
    <>

      {showForm && selectedItem && (
        <div className="form-container">
          <Container maxWidth="sm">
            <Box
              sx={{
                bgcolor: 'White',
                padding: '30px',
                border: '1px solid gray',
                borderRadius: '8px',
                boxShadow: '0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '50%',
                left: '50%',
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                marginTop: '420px',
                width: '700px',
              }}
            >
            <GreenTop>
              <GreenHeading>Données de la demande</GreenHeading>
            </GreenTop>
              <div id="map" style={{ height: '300px', margin: '10px 0' }}></div>
              
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default AllDemande;
```

[a screenshot of my problem where the map does not load :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY25Y.png)

I checked everything and it looks correct to me:

- the bingmap api key
- the code in a new project
- dependencies
- imports
- the version of ol

Comment: Open devtools and check if you have any messages in the console, also open the network tab and check if the client is trying to load any tiles from Bing

Comment: Open Network tab and filter out images if you see a fetch of tile Images to the server and there is an error there, your problem is with the BingMaps Config or apikey.

Comment: that what i found in network and i don't know what that mean :
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial?uriScheme=https&include=ImageryProviders&key=AopTMqA_hL6-A7_10Y_HifSekPW-cyOZXVWDB-L-GuLnf8Mw6yyMPBHRObHIZtFs&c=en-us&jsonp=olc_31